# Is it possible to use the graphviz package on ShareLaTeX?

Tags: sharelatex, shell-escape

I am trying to use the `graphviz` package on ShareLaTeX. I have included both the `graphviz` and `graphicx` packages

```
\usepackage[pdf]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphviz}
```

I tried running the simple example from the [`graphviz` documentation](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/graphviz/graphviz.pdf):

```
\digraph[scale=0.5]{abc}{rankdir=LR; a->b->c;}
```

But I get an error in my PDF saying:

> The file abc.ps hasn’t been created from abc.dot yet.Run ‘dot -Tps -o
>   abc.ps abc.dot’ to create it.Or invoke LATEX with the -shell-escape
>   option to have this done automatically.

I have read elsewhere that including the `--shell-escape` option is not possible in ShareLaTeX (please correct me if I am wrong), so is there another way to embed `graphviz` (or dot as it were) into a document on ShareLaTeX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com), which [permits](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/216-examples-techniques-and-tips-on-how-to-use-latexmkrc-with-overleaf) the use of `--shell-escape` and has a [`graphviz` example](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/graphviz-drawing-example/xhrpxynbfxvw).